# Lodash fp (functional programming) reduce not working how I expect it to work

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

Using normal lodash without fp, you'd do something like

```
chain(array).map(..).reduce(...).value()
```

With fp, you'd do

```
compose(reduce(...), map(...))(array)
```

I can make it work for many methods (flatten, sort, map), except reduce.

You'd expect it (lodash/fp/reduce) to work like

```
reduce((a,b)=>a+b, 0)([1,2,3])
```

But the fp version still requires 3 arguments, which doesn't make sense to me. All the other functions work like this for me, except reduce

```
func(...)(array)
```

How can I make fpreduce work like other fp functions in this manner:

```
compose(reduce(...), map(...), flatten(...))(array)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @hackerrdave The question is, how to make it work like all the other fp functions? In a composable fashion. Since all the other fp functions work fine that way, except reduce, I am trying to find what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

reduce takes 3 total arguments regardless of whether a functional interface is used. `lodash/fp` just changes parameter order and allows you to partially functions

```
const fp = require ('lodash/fp')

const sum = fp.reduce (fp.add, 0)

const sq = x => x * x

const main = fp.compose (sum, fp.map (sq))

console.log (main ([1,2,3,4]))
// => 30
// [1,2,3,4] => [1,4,9,16] => 0 + 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 => 30
```

---

Or as an inline composition

```
fp.compose (fp.reduce (fp.add, 0), fp.map (x => x * x)) ([1,2,3,4])
// => 30
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I now realize what I did wrong. I wasn't providing the starting value (not sure what it's called). I am used to not using it in Array.reduce(), so out of habit didn't put it there. I was also converting chain.map.reduce.value, which also doesn't use it. Silly me.

Comment: Consider using `fp.flow` to `fp.compose`, the inverted order might feel more natural. `fp.compose` is an alias of `fp.flowRight`.

Comment: how to populate the second param with the first item in the array of data being passed in as third param? For example, if implementing a Max function... (where -1 is the possible max value etc).  Wish to map over Max with an array of numbers so can't just manually pass in the second value.

Comment: I went with `var max = _.reduce((cur, acc) => greater(cur, acc), Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);`